# Get Sub OU via Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have to write a program that lists all sub OUs from a Parent OU. But the problem is, that there are more sub OUs under the sub OUs i need. But i have to ignore those Sub-Sub OUs

**Example:**

Parent OU:

```
OU=Hosting,DC=blub,DC=example,DC=ch
```

Now i need the OUs like:

```
OU=Baug,OU=Hosting,DC=blub,DC=example,DC=ch
```

But i have to ignore this:

```
OU=User,OU=Baug,OU=Hosting,DC=blub,DC=example,DC=ch
```

**My code:**

```
$OU = 'OU=Hosting,DC=blub,DC=example,DC=ch'

Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope Subtree -Filter * | 
 Select-Object DistinguishedName, Name
```

With this I get all existing Sub OUs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` has a `-SearchScope` parameter. You can use the setting `onelevel` with this to return only the first level OUs:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $OU -Filter * -SearchScope OneLevel
```